# Are there any wildcard characters for usage with stripos?

Tags: php, wildcard

As the heading suggests, are there any wildcard characters(like % or * in c++) for usage with stripos()?
I was planning to use preg_match but it says on ["The preg_match Manual"](https://www.php.net/preg_match) that I should use strpos() or strstr() if I need to search for a string within a string as it is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, stripos() does not accept any wildcards, it expects a literal string to use for matching.

stripos - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: Ok, Is there any makeshift way for that? I will mark your answer as correct, as apparently there is no direct way to do that!